# How can I securely store the IP address, username and password of a database using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, configuration, passwords, password-protection

I have Node.js code to connect to a [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database:

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var connection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 50,
      host     : 'ip',
    user     : 'username',
      password : 'pass',
      database : 'mydb'
});


app.get('/', function(req, resp) {
    connection.getConnection(function(error, tempCont) {
        if(!!error) {
            tempCont.release();
            console.log('Error');
        } else {
            console.log('Connected!');

            tempCont.query("select * from table", function(error, rows, fields) {
                tempCont.release();
                if(!!error) {
                    console.log('Error in the query');
                } else {
                    resp.json(rows);
                }
            });
        }
    })
})

console.log("listening requests...")
app.listen(1337);
```

How do I secure an IP address, username and password used for connecting to a database so that is not visible in the code or configuration file?

Comment: Put your database credentials in a not versioned separate config file.

Comment: I have that approach/example as well. Wondering if there is a way not to see a password at all if someone who is not authorized - connect to the same server and start scanning all the files..

Comment: If an unauthorized person can connect to the server, you have a very serious security problem.

Comment: Correct but that probably does not justify enough that passwords should be left open as a plain text format.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Install the *dotenv* module by: **npm install --save dotenv**

Create a .env file at the root folder and write down the code:

```
DB_CONLIMIT=50
DB_HOST=ip
DB_USER=username
DB_PASSWORD=pass
DB_DATABASE=mydb
```

In your JavaScript file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

var connection = mysql.createPool({

     connectionLimit : process.env.DB_CONLIMIT,
     host            : process.env.DB_HOST,
     user            : process.env.DB_USER ,
     password        : process.env.DB_PASSWORD ,
     database        : process.env.DB_DATABASE
});
```

Comment: @blakemade there is no requirement of ' or " in .env file

Answer (score 3):

You should be configuring your systems so that your service runs as its own user with its own protected files. This offers some protection so that even if another service is compromised, the intruding user's access is isolated from other components of your system. Don't run things as root.

As for how secrets are stored and accessed, that's up to you. You can have a configuration file if you want. Another option is to use environment variables. Ultimately; however, your secrets are going to have to be stored in plaintext somewhere for your system to read and use.

Another method worth mentioning is you could possibly separate your secrets from your applications by having a dedicated secrets service. All your applications would have to know about this service and from there they could request the secrets they need for their regular operation. This has the obvious caveat of all your applications depend on the secrets service on start up - if that goes down your applications won't be able to start or restart.